# Реализация авторизации mail.ru через fuel kotlin

Tags: kotlin, авторизация, mail.ru

Пишу приложение на `андроид` для связи с облаком `mail.ru`. Застопорился на авторизации, пишу такой код:

```
val bodyJson = """
{
    "Login" : "login",
    "Password" : "password",
    "Domain" : "mail.ru"
}
""".trimIndent()

val (request, response, result) = Fuel
.post("https://auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth")
.body(bodyJson).response()
```

в response мне возвращается просто страница `mail.ru` с `200` кодом независимо от логина и пароля.
Смотрел чужие реализации на `php` и `c#`, делал по аналогии. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
val (request, response, result) = Fuel
.post("https://auth.mail.ru/cgi-bin/auth", bodyJson)
.response()
```

Вот так попробуйте.

Comment: В таком виде не получится, ведь post принимает list of pairs. Но, да, я пробовал передавать значения как параметры.